# How to mock with JestJS injected dependency in class ES6?

Tags: node.js, mocking, jestjs

I'm trying to get some dependance inversion going in a small NodeJS project. I want to have mocked instances of personal classes that I can inject in other classes.

This is for the lates node and jest version, I have read Jest documentation and nothing seem to be what I'm looking for.

```
class A {

    getStr(): string {
        return "bob";
    }
}

class B {
    private a: A;

    constructor(a: A){
        this.a = a;
    }

    getA(): string {
        return a.getStr();
    }
}

const b = new B(mocked instance of A)
```

I expect to be able to interact with the injected mock and see if it's been called in unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you would like to spy on the functions of A, you could do it as follows (if you would like to keep using classes notation):

```
class MockA {
    constructor() {
       this.getStr = jest.fn()
    }
}

const mockedA = new MockA()
const b = new B(mockedA)
```

Then to test that it was called, you could do it as follows:

```
b.getA();
expect(a.getStr.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

To create the mock without the class, you could do so as follows:

```
const mockedGetStr = jest.fn()
const b = new B({ getStr: mockedGetStr })
b.getA();
expect(a.getStr.mock.calls.length).toBe(1)
```

Comment: Oh do you think there's a way with less setup I have a lot of classes with multiple dependance like : `constructor (a: A, b: B, c: C, d: D)'` it would be a huge setup doing it the way of your answer. Thank you for the help anyway it helps me to understand a bit more.

Comment: @ThamiAmrani I have added the bit at the end to show a more brief way of doing so.